# Gradle Sync Failed: Basic Functionality will not work

Tags: intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.2, gradle-tooling-api

I checked all solutions and I got the answer that I need to update the Android -Studio version.

1. Android Studio: 3.2
2. Gradle Version: 5.1.1
3. Android Plugin Version: 3.4.2

This problem raised when I was trying to integrate Youtube API.

Gradle (project):

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

Tried to update AS version, but still, it is showing AS 3.2

```
    android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mateiladesign.practice.com.materialdesign"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0 alpha-03' //2.2.0-alpha03  2.0.0-alpha01
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
//AndroidX
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0 alpha09' //1.0.0-alpha03
//Recycler
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
//Hodenhof Circle ImageView
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
//Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
//YTAPI
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```

}

What do I do to resolve this issue?

```
    Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;
```

Comment: You need to update IDE itself, not the dependency. Please download and install the latest version: https://developer.android.com/studio

Comment: IDE means Android Studio latest version 3.4.2?

Comment: Problem solved by using:
Build.gradle(Project):
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' 

Gradle  wrapper properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip